# Disabling touchevents on overlaying div so underlying div receives them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working on a mobile web gallery where users can drag slide images left and right and all works great with that.

The problem is that when I overlay a div with absolute positioning that has a button within it the touch event's for the div underneath don't seem to be firing. I've tried `pointer-events:none;` on the overlaying div but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there away to disable touch-events through the overlaying div so the div on the bottom of the z-index receives them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the touch event on the overlaying div and delegate it to the underlying div to simulate this

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$('#myOtherDiv').trigger(event);
});
```

Something along those lines (either use `.trigger` or just `.click` on the underlying div)